# How to remove a version of camel from Apache Karaf?

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, apache-karaf, karaf

In Apache Karaf there is camel version 2.15.0, I wish to remove this version and install version 2.14.0.

I believe this installed version 2.14.0 as when I do feature:list I see camel version 2.14.0 but I also see the 2.15.0 still there. How to make the 2.15.0 go away?

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add camel 2.14.0
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.14.0/xml/features
karaf@root()>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Karaf does not come with Camel out of the box. You install Camel into it. It should have commands to remove a repo-url also.

You can also just clean your Karaf, but shutting it down, and delete the data directory, and you have a vanilla Karaf again.

And there is a shorthand to install Camel with

```
features:chooseurl camel 2.14.2
```

But beware in Karaf 3.x onwards some of the commands have been renamed and changed so its something else there :(

Comment: Yes the command names have been changed in the newer versions which is slightly annoying because many of the documentations on the web no longer apply, I have to guess what the new name means. 
Although the names seem better.

Comment: when installing a specific feature you also can put the version to it. For example feature:install camel/2.14.2